# zabbix rc Releases

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I have recently started using Zabbix release 2.0.7 and faced few issues

1) On the Zabbix page (for example : http://www.zabbix.com/rn2.0.7rc1.php ) I see that for there RC releases Zabbix says

**"This release is not for production use. It is a Release Candidate!"**

What is the meaning of release candidate if cannot be used for production release . May be I am not understanding Zabbix terminology here .

2) ok . Since Zabbix prohibited me from using its 2.0.7 rc1 release , I installed 2.0.7 and on my Zabbix PAGE I see the following errors though all triggers etc are getting captured perfectly fine .

What can i be doing wrong . I have taken all the rpms from zabbix download site & not changed a single line of code .

[image]

```
Constant UNRESOLVED_MACRO_STRING already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:24]
Constant HISTORY_OF_ACTIONS_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:27]
Constant EVENT_ACTION_MESSAGES_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:28]
Constant EVENT_ACTION_CMDS_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:29]
Constant HISTORY_LOG_LOCALTIME_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:30]
Constant HISTORY_LOG_ITEM_PLAINTEXT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:31]
Constant HISTORY_PLAINTEXT_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:32]
Constant HISTORY_ITEM_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:33]
Constant EVENTS_DISCOVERY_TIME_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:34]
Constant EVENTS_ACTION_TIME_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:35]
Constant QUEUE_NODES_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:36]
Constant CHARTBAR_HOURLY_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:37]
Constant CHARTBAR_DAILY_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:38]
Constant REPORT4_ANNUALLY_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:40]
Constant REPORT4_MONTHLY_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:41]
Constant REPORT4_DAILY_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:42]
Constant REPORT4_WEEKLY_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:43]
Constant REPORTS_BAR_REPORT_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:45]
Constant POPUP_PERIOD_CAPTION_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:46]
Constant MAPS_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:47]
Constant SERVER_INFO_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:48]
Constant XML_DATE_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:49]
Constant XML_TIME_DATE_FORMAT already defined [include/translateDefines.inc.php:50]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Release candidate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Release_candidate) in any terminology usually means that the software "should work" however, the vendor doesn't guarantee 100% stability and lack of errors.
2. Most probably you have some leftovers from the previous installation. The PHP error you get usually means that some file was included twice or a file from different version was included.

I strongly advice to use the packages from your distribution.

Comment: hey i started using new rps but still get these error . I mean i do not change source code , just use these rpms and deleted old rpms from my repro... Which all files should i remove or check ???

Comment: `grep -r SERVER_INFO_DATE_FORMAT /where/your/zabbix/files/are` will be a good start.